# Opening page in CURL give different results than in browser

Tags: php, curl

Well, im trying to open page http://gratka.pl using curl to get it's content, unfortunatelly they seems to have very good protection against it. My code (in ZEND FW):

```
    $client = new \Zend\Http\Client;
    $client->setHeaders($options);
    $adapter = new \Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl();

    $agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; chromeframe/13.0.782.218; chromeframe; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)';
    //$agent = 'Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)';
    $header=array(
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12',
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate',
        'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
        'Keep-Alive: 115',
        'Connection: keep-alive',
    );

    $clientOptions = array(
        'curloptions' => array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
            //CURLOPT_ENCODING => "gzip",
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $agent,
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
            CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'cookie.txt',
            CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => 'cookie.txt',
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
            CURLOPT_REFERER => "http://google.com",
            //CURLOPT_COOKIE => 'sesja_gratka=065ad930ce08fa203b39e2599f19e345; __gfp_64b=8IF3rdQKeCJiUBB.P4vNx3KWyCYii.16iOnjxq.C6tz.77; PHPSESSID=26f34d5c637c9db9c752695b2a2db427; __utmc=239465948',
        ),
    );

    $client->setOptions($clientOptions);
    $client->setAdapter($adapter);  
    $client->setUri($url);
    $result = $client->send();
    $cookies = $client->getCookies();
    $header = $result->getHeaders();
    $body = $result->getBody();
    var_dump($body);die;
    var_dump(htmlspecialchars($header));die;
```

I was trying many options and things but still the same - didn't get the cookies, didn't get the body... Except the valid site content I'm getting all the time page that says - 'You are temporary blocked". While opening same site with browser everything is fine.

Comment: You are setting different `User-Agent`s in both the `HTTPHEADER` and `USERAGENT` options - which one wins?

Comment: @w3d Well, both - one appears as  ["HTTP_USERAGENT"], second one as ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]. This is the output of $_SERVER of my curl request: http://bwdesign.sldc.pl/zend/public/import

Comment: Well, there can only be one `User-Agent` HTTP request header (or at least only one will be read by the server). My only thought here is that if the server saw `Firefox/3.6` it might consider this "too old to be a real user" and block it?

Comment: Well, still nothing, I've changed headers to the same as my browser but still have no access. Is there anything else I can do? How exactly they could know that I'm accessing their page through some "bot"? Only that I can't run JS via curl is the difference I guess, but can't be sure.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think they necessarily have any unusual protection, plugging that URL in an online CURL tool (such as web-sniffer.net) returns a valid response. If the page was dependent on JS to render content then you should be able to "view source" in your browser to see the same response (or even try disabling JS in your browser).

Comment: ...I've also tried my own basic PHP CURL script, with minimal request headers (not even setting a `User-Agent`) and this also returns a valid response. Are you setting `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`? Since the URL given actually redirects to the `www` subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

If the `cookie.txt` is generated, then empty it and run the curl again. May be it is blocking you based on the value of the cookie.

If the `cookie.txt` file is not generated, then use absolute path, for example `/var/xyz/cookie.txt` and also check whether you have write permission on the file so that curl can write cookie on that.

Also, what does the verbose mode return?? You can match the request with the requests with your browser. Are you running the browser and your curl on same PC? Or its deployed in your server? Just for crosschecking!